# GeoServer renders blue and red backgrounds occasionally

Tags: geoserver, style, rendering

It looks like this:
[image]
As you can see some tiles are rendered correctly.

Our data source is an mbtiles file, styled with a [mapbox style](https://github.com/openmaptiles/maptiler-basic-gl-style/blob/master/style.json) (we had to install mbtiles and mbstyles extensions).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Also bare in mind that the mbtiles datastore is a community module with no or little support,

Comment: @IanTurton I haven't found seemingly useful logs yet. I'll post them if I do.

Comment: You'll probably need to attach a debugger and see what's happen in side the module then. Hard to diagnose, especially if it's intermitent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the mbtiles layers from the layer group and only let the style remain there. The map renders correctly now.

The issue was probably that the layers were being rendered multiple times, once with the style and once without, sometimes the styled layer covered the unstyled, and sometimes the other way around (depending on which one rendered faster).